# electron, папка build не помещается в сборку

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

Есть сборка приложения на electron, но при сборке в него не помещается build, а все остальные папки и файлы помещаются. Почему так.
Вот package.json:

```
{
  "name": "chance-admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.58",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nfc-pcsc": "^0.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "wait-on": "^5.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "13.1.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.10.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "electron-build": "yarn build && electron-builder",
    "build:app": "yarn electron-build --dir",
    "build:all": "yarn electron-build build -mwl",
    "build:mac": "yarn electron-build build --mac",
    "build:linux": "yarn electron-build build --linux",
    "build:windows": "yarn electron-build build --windows --x64",
    "start:client": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run start:client\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""
  },
  "build": {
    "asar": false,
    "productName": "chance-admin",
    "appId": "com.chance-admin.package",
    "extends": null,
    "mac": {
      "artifactName": "${productName}-${version}-osx.${ext}",
      "category": "public.app-category.productivity",
      "target": [
        "dmg"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "artifactName": "${productName}-${version}-${arch}-linux.${ext}",
      "maintainer": "xxxx",
      "target": [
        "deb"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "zip"
      ]
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

electron.js:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');
const server = require('../server');

const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1000, height: 800 });
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? 'http://localhost:3000'
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`
  );
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => (mainWindow = null));
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit();
});
app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: есть репозиторий проекта?

Comment: нет, что-то еще необходимо показать?

Comment: показано достаточно, но проще ответить на этот вопрос прогнав билд приложения, чем фантазировать что куда кладётся и как собирается

Comment: если прогнать build то будет все кроме папки build в electron приложении